# meaning of the phrase "be so doing"?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/o69TvQqyGdg). It is at around 30 second. Here is the context:

> Mr. Green, Mr. Green, if it is really that simple, I **am so getting** an A in this class.

Comment: It simply means **I am definitely getting an A in this class**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly note: in the past 15 years, more or less, so has started being used in  place of "very much".

- I will very much [so] be getting an A in this class.
- He is very much [so] going tonight. [meaning: he is very much going tonight]

Nowadays, "so", an adverb (not when it is a conjunction or used to start speaking),is used to emphasize verbs. Some of this is traditional:*I so want to go. [I want to go so much.]*

But, when it precedes a verb as in "so going tonight"; "so doing that"; so liking this", that use is not traditional and young people use it all the time. It would be considered informal register.

[very much](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/very-much)

Comment: Indeed, it is _so_ considered an informal register.

Comment: @J.R. I was wondering if it was originally "valley speak." Can't figure out where it came from. Snowboarding?

Answer (score 1):

It is a colloquialism used by "the younger generation".  You won't hear grandma and grandpa saying it.

> You are *so* getting into trouble for that!

Emphasis on **so**.

You are going to get into trouble "big-time" for doing that.